# android.net.wifi.WIFI_HOTSPOT_CLIENTS_CHANGED alternative

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to implement a way to listen to a client's connection event on the smartphone hotspot. I see that android.net.wifi.WIFI_HOTSPOT_CLIENTS_CHANGED is no longer avaible. How can i do this? I think that this is possible because the smartphone notify me when i client make a connection to the smartphone hotspot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the Intent Action...You have to use a custom method, i'l suggest you create a background thread that checks/reads the I.P table  (/proc/net/arp) constantly and update you...here's a snippet I've used.

Read i.p list table

```
public ArrayList<String> getConnectedDevices() {
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList();
try {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/net/arp"));
    while (true) {
        String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
        if (readLine == null) {
            break;
        }
        String[] split = readLine.split(" +");
        if (split != null && split.length >= 4) {
            arrayList.add(split[0]);
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return arrayList;
}
```

Create runnable to check

```
class CheckHotSpotConnection implements Runnable {
private CheckHotSpotConnection() {
}

public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while (discoverClient()) {
        i = getConnectedDevices().size();
        if (i > 1) {
            //client discovered

           //disable client discovery to end thread
        } else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Start Thread

```
 new Thread(new CheckHotSpotConnection()).start();
```